# CSS Slideshow not working in other browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, slideshow

I have been using a simple CSS/HTML slideshow on my website. It has been great on Chrome, until I viewed my site on IE8. Some of the CSS wasn't working and the slideshow was broken with all the photos stacked on top of each other. What is the best way to make my CSS compatible with all browsers?

HTML:

```
<div class="css-slideshow" id="container">
<figure><img alt="Air Compressor" height="370" src="images/air-compressor.jpg" width="495" /> <figcaption><strong>Air Compressor</strong>      </figcaption></figure>

<figure><img alt=" Battery Charger" height="370" src="images/battery-charger.jpg" width="495" /> <figcaption><strong>Battery Charger</strong> </figcaption></figure>

<figure><img alt="Engine Hoist" height="370" src="images/engine-hoist.jpg" width="495" /> <figcaption><strong>Engine Hoist</strong> </figcaption></figure>

<figure><img alt="Floor Jack" height="370" src="images/floor-jack.jpg" width="495" /> <figcaption><strong>Floor Jack</strong></figcaption></figure>

<figure><img alt="Jumper Cables" height="370" src="images/jumper-cables.jpg" width="495" /> <figcaption><strong>Jumper Cables</strong></figcaption></figure>

<figure><img alt="Air Impact Wrench" height="370" src="images/air-impact-wrench.jpg" width="495" /> <figcaption><strong>Air Impact Wrench</strong></figcaption></figure>

<figure><img alt=" Car Stand" height="370" src="images/car-stand.jpg" width="495" /> <figcaption><strong>Car Stand</strong></figcaption></figure>

<figure><img alt="Dewalt Impact Wrench" height="370" src="images/dewalt-impact-wrench.jpg" width="495" /> <figcaption><strong>Dewalt Impact Wrench</strong></figcaption></figure>
```

CSS:

```
.css-slideshow{
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 max-width: 495px;
 height: 370px;
 margin: 0em auto;
 width:75%;
 }
.css-slideshow figure{
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 }

.css-slideshow img {
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;}

.css-slideshow figcaption{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 color: #fff;
 background: rgba(0,0,0, .3);
 font-size: .8em;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity .5s;
  }
.css-slideshow:hover figure figcaption{
 transition: opacity .5s;
 opacity: 1;
 }
.css-slideshow figure{
 opacity:0;
 }
 figure:nth-child(1) {
 animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(2) {
 animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(3) {
 animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(4) {
 animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(5) {
 animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(6) {
 animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(7) {
 animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(8) {
 animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
 }

@keyframes xfade{
  0%{
  opacity: 1;
 }
  10.5% {
  opacity:1;
 }
  12.5%{
  opacity: 0;
 }
  98% {
  opacity:0;
 }
   100% {
  opacity:1;
 }
 }

#container {
display: flex;              /* establish flex container */
flex-direction: column;     /* stack flex items vertically */
justify-content: center;    /* center items vertically, in this case */
align-items: center;        /* center items horizontally, in this case */
height: 370px;
}
```

Comment: IE8 is gone, it's passed away, it's simply a thing of the past..

Comment: it works in ie11, i wouldn't worry about anything below that

Comment: Thanks. I haven't taken the time to update IE since I never use it. It was brought to my attention to check browser compatibility and opened my site in what I had and grew worried.